# CGAL error: assertion violation! When using "CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::extrude_mesh()"

Tags: cgal

#Issue Details
I loaded my own mesh file (.obj) which is creadted by another library called "open3D". The reconstruction method is “Ball pivoting”. I want to use the"Extrude_mesh()" to get an extrusion model, and the direction of extrusion is only negative to the z-axis. The code compiles fine, but when I run it after a few minutes I get an error like this:

CGAL error: assertion violation!
Expression : idx < data.size()
File : D:\Programs\dev\CGAL-5.5.1\include\CGAL\Surface_mesh\Properties.h
Line : 193
Explanation:
Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at https://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html

#Source Code
`
#include
#include
#include
#include
#include
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/compute_normal.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/extrude.h>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/IO/polygon_mesh_io.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/OBJ.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/IO/polygon_mesh_io.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include<CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/border.h>

```
typedef:
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh SM;
typedef Kernel::Vector_3 Vector;


auto start = std::clock();
double extrudeVector[3] = { 0, 0, -500 };
SM mesh;
SM outMesh;
CGAL::IO::read_polygon_mesh(v2, mesh);
CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::extrude_mesh(mesh, outMesh, *new Vector(extrudeVector[0],    extrudeVector[1], extrudeVector[2]));
mesh.clear();
CGAL::IO::write_polygon_mesh(v82, outMesh, CGAL::parameters::stream_precision(17));
endTime = clock();
std::cout << "时间是（ms）:" << endTime - startTime;
return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

`

#Environment
Operating system (Windows/Mac/Linux, 32/64 bits): Windows 64 bits
Compiler: isual Studio 2019
Release or debug mode: debug
Specific flags used (if any):
CGAL version: 5.5.1
Boost version: 1.71.0
Other libraries versions if used (Eigen, TBB, etc.): Eigen 3

I want to be able to stretch my surface model into a bulk model.
A picture of the surface model can be found in the attachment
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFd19.png)

Comment: Can you put that on gist.github,com and also share the data so that we can try to reproduce and propose a fix.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me, I have solved my problem and I am sorry that I wrote my own code incorrectly.